# Exclude Free Shipping for Specific State: Magento 2.3.1

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping, magento2.3.1

how to off free shipping for specific states.

Example:

I have free shipping for all items over item total $100, calculated by FedEx.

I do not want to have free shipping for USA state of Hawaii, Alaska.

Please advice.

Thank you,

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?